# Use XML generated from PHP file vs a physical .xml file

Tags: php, ajax, xml

I hope I am asking this the correct way and thanks in advance for any advice! I have been trying to utilize this tutorial for a part on my own site:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

After trying many versions of my own code unsuccessfully, I decided to go ahead and step by step walk through the tutorial - even creating a new MYSQL DB exactly like in the tutorial...

In the tutorial example, they use an actual .xml file to read the data from:

```
// Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
```

However, just like the commented line says above the code "PHP File" - meaning you could use a PHP file there instead of an .xml file which would then dynamically generate the XML code based on the DB query.

They show 3 different ways to get the XML code from the DB and I have tried all 3 ways with the same exact results.

- When I run the index.html page I get just the map showing up with no markers at all
- If I run just the php file that generates the XML code, nothing shows up in the browser (just a blank white page) -- HOWEVER -- when I view the page source, it shows me the XML perfectly!
- If I take that generated XML from my PHP file and copy/paste it into an .xml file and then call that .xml file in the downloadurl function, it all works perfectly!

So, therein lies my question.

What piece am I missing that would allow me to use the PHP file to dynamically generate the XML versus needing a separate XML file in my directory too.

The code I am using is the same exact code they have in the tutorial page.

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT - here are the 2 php pages. The convert-xml.php is for generating the info from MYSQL db. It's, getting the info from the db because when I view source it shows the xml tree like it should be. It;'s just not writing it to the browser or working in the downloadurl function to display the markers on the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('convert-xml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_IS_HERE&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**convert-xml.php**

```
<?php require 'conn-info.php';?>

<?php 
// Start XML file, create parent node 
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0"); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false
$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$node = $dom->createElement("markers"); 
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// connect to db 
$membermap_conn = mysql_connect($membermap_server, $membermap_user, $membermap_password, $membermap_database); 
if ($membermap_conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $membermap_conn->connect_errno . ") " . $membermap_conn->connect_error; }

// select the db 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($membermap_database, $membermap_conn); 
if (!$db_selected) {   
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error()); 
}

// Pull the zip / user information out of the database. 
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";


$result = mysql_query($query); 
if (!$result) {   
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each 
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   
// Add to XML document node   
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");   
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
$newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);   
$newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);   
$newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);   
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);   
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);   
$newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']); }

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Comment: 1. Sounds like a JS/HTML issue. Have you opened the developer console. 2. I'd guess isn't generating an XML file

Comment: Are you sure you have `header("Content-type: text/xml");` to show the file as the content is being created and sent (If I understand it properly)

Comment: yes, using the developer console. When I switch the code back ot try to use the PHP file again, it loads the map but no markers. When I look at the console I get an error on 2 lines, it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null -- and it gives 2 line numbers and here are the 2 lines of code: var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker'); and then also this line: callback(request, request.status);

Comment: yes I have this line in the PHP fle that generates the XML: header("Content-type: text/xml");

Comment: Anyone else? Thank you!

Comment: Is the site online? It sounds like the AJAX isn't returning.

Comment: yes site is on a test server but I just posted my 2 code pages in the original post..hope that helps!